# What does AをBにしたら mean?

Tags: grammar

In the manga strip below, the character says:

> 艦長も芽依先輩をラーメンにしたら絶対おいしいと思うでしょ？

What does 依先輩をラーメンにしたら exactly mean here? The only にしたら structure I could find was Noun + にしたら, which means something like "from someone's perspective", but I don't know how it fits here because in my context, the noun is "ramen", not a person or a sentient being.

[image: manga]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sentence has the `AをBにする` construction meaning "to turn A into B", "to make A B" or "to consider A as B". She's talking about ramen made of Mei-senpai.

> 艦長も芽依先輩をラーメンにしたら絶対おいしいと思うでしょ？
>
> Captain, you also think it would be absolutely delicious if we made Mei-senpai into ramen, don't you?

Note that the girl is saying 好きな人は芽依先輩 and 好きな食べ物も芽依先輩か in the previous frames.